# Write in short to Map object into Array using SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift

I have a function map object into Array in **Swift 4.2**:

```
var arrayLoop = dictionary["display_resources"].arrayValue

var displayRss = [DisplayResources]()
for var o in arrayLoop {
    displayRss.append(DisplayResources(dict: o))
}
```

How can I write it in short by using `map`:

```
displayRss = DisplayResources(dict: dictionary["display_resources"].arrayValue.map{ $0 }))  // Not right
```

Comment: Hi, is `DisplayResources` your data class? If it is, in your last last line you invoke init of this class, so how could we know what actually is wrong without seeing this init method. But at least it is strange to see `Map` function what doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the function that you are applying to each element of `arrayLoop` inside the `map`. In this case, it is the initialiser for `DisplayResources`:

```
displayRss = dictionary["display_resources"].arrayValue.map { DisplayResources(dict: $0) }
```

Or simply:

```
displayRss = dictionary["display_resources"].arrayValue.map(DisplayResources.init)
```